# Can i save script files directly on database and get them back or run them?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I was wondering if i can save some sort of script files directly on the database and run them in

```
<canvas></canvas>
```

(E.g adsense ad codes);

it is a script and i can not edit my source codes all the time to past new codes when i change them. there for i thought save them on the database and retrieve them in the pages i want from database to html 5 canvas tag.

**But how to sanatize or validate them in a protected way( To make sure no one can hack my website )**

Typically im using php5 filter sanatizing to validate my inputs.
But it will remove all the scripts and thing from sricpts if i use that similar method.I need something advance.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You could save it in a database. You have to create a column with type TEXT and the right encoding. But saving script into a database is a very unconventional method in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you, How can i save a script then ? 
I have used blogger.com for several years and i saw on their dashbord we have a option to save adsense or any script we wants to run and save it. then it'll display what the script say.
Any suggestion ?